# Map vim keys based on OS?

Tags: vim

### Background

---

I use VIM on both MacOS and windows, with just one vimrc setting

And here's one of my *lightweight* key mapping binding:

```
map <leader>cmd:exec has("mac")==1? ':!open -a terminal' : ':！start cmd'
```

### Problem

---

However, it doesn't work as I thought: press `<leader>cmd` and **without** pressing an enter key then cmd or terminal pops out.

What actually happens is the whole mapping string

`exec has("mac")==1? ':!open -a terminal' : ':！start cmd'` just appears in ex mode and waits for me to press the enter key to run itself.

As I know, if you use `exe "your cmd string"` in your mapping key setting , you don't need put a `<cr>` after it, but why when you are using the triple operator, it behaves differently?

### Try

---

So I put  into the string, like

```
map <leader>cmd:exec has("mac")==1? ':!open -a terminal<cr>' : ':！start cmd<cr>'
```

vim tells me:

[image]

(Also, I cannot figure out why `<cr>`in ``` `` ``` should be escaped, isn't that a string in ``` `` ``` remains the original meaning?)

So I modified as following:

```
map <leader>cmd:exec has("mac")==1? ':!open -a terminal\<cr\>' : ':！start cmd\<cr\>'
```

But it just appears in ex mode again.

**Any solutions, please?**

Comment: Did you mean `:exec has("mac")==1? ':!open -a terminal' : ':!start cmd'<CR>`?

Comment: @melpomene Amazing! It works! But why `:exec ':!open -a terminal' without <cr> works too?

Comment: It shouldn't. It should simply prefill the command without executing it.

Comment: @melpomene You're right, I am confused why I myself thought it should work..nevertheless, tks bro!

Comment: @melpomene And do you think my key binding solution is a good one or there're better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's clean up your command a little:

```
:nnoremap <leader>cmd :execute has("mac") ? "!open -a terminal" : "!start cmd"
```

- `nnoremap` is better than `map` because it ensures non-recursiveness and it's explicit about the mode it's made for,
- no need to test the value of `has()`,
- shortened names are cool for typing in the command-line but they are useless in script,
- the `:` are redundant.

But none of that will actually fix your problem, namely that you don't have a carriage return at the end of your mapping:

```
:nnoremap <leader>cmd :execute has("mac") ? "!open -a terminal" : "!start cmd"<CR>
```

And you still have to press `<CR>` a second time anyway to get back to Vim so…

```
:nnoremap <leader>cmd :execute has("mac") ? "!open -a terminal" : "!start cmd"<CR><CR>
```

---

Now, here is a pretty clean and generic way to do things differently depending on the platform:

```
" Define a global variable containing the current environment's name
" if it hasn't been already defined.
if !exists('g:env')
    if has('win64') || has('win32') || has('win16')
        let g:env = 'WINDOWS'
    else
        let g:env = toupper(substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', ''))
    endif
endif
```

and a reworked version of your mapping, with an added path for the `open` command which you may or may not need depending on your use case:

```
nnoremap <leader>cmd :execute g:env == "DARWIN" ? "!open -a terminal ." : "!start cmd"<CR><CR>
```

and an alternative approach, just for the fun of it:

```
let cmds = { "DARWIN": "!open -a terminal .", "WINDOWS": "!start cmd" }
nnoremap <leader>cmd :execute cmds[g:env]<CR><CR>
```

Comment: Holy moly, thanks for your great answer! BTW, if I put the g:env definition block into vimrc, from when can I use it? Should I put it to a function and call the function in VimEnter autocmd if I want to use the g:env at very first?

Comment: You can put it as-is, near the top of your `vimrc`. Next time you source your `vimrc` the `g:env` variable will be set and usable in any function/mapping/command anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to @romainl's answer, you don't need to dynamically evaluate the operating system during mapping execution (the operating system can hardly change while Vim is running; this is static information). Therefore, it's much easier to *define* the mappings conditionally:

```
if has("mac")
    nnoremap <leader>cmd :!open -a terminal<CR>
else
    nnoremap <leader>cmd :!start cmd<CR>
endif
```

This let's you get rid of the `:execute`, is a bit faster, and much easier to extend or tweak. (All the other caveats about [`:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) and the missing `<CR>` from @romainl's answer still apply.)